# updating chart data in powerpoint using "copyfromrecordset"

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am really hoping you can help me out here.After browsing google/stack overflow a million times i luckily stumbled on this old post. 
I am trying to update the chart data using "copyfromrecordset" and i get a string of errors like "subscript out of range" etc. I followed your logic exactly as you stated above until the step

```
With chtData
    Set cTable = chtData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1)
' Here, you can update the ListObject in the same ways you
' would do so in Excel, natively.
```

'in this piece, i got the data from sql server and copied it into record set. when i try to update the chart data to get the data from record set , it doesnt work.
End With"
can you please please help me out here?

Thanks a lot

```
Sub ShowChartData() Dim sld As Slide 
Dim shp As Shape Dim cht As Chart Dim chtData As ChartData Dim cTable As 
ObjectSet sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) 
Set shp = sld.Shapes("New") 'Handle the chart
Set cht = shp.Chart 
Set chtData = cht.ChartData chtData.ActivateWith chtData Set cTable = 
chtData.Workbook, 
'sql connection (hidden)
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection 
rst.Open StrQuery, Cn ' Dim wbs As Object 
cTable.Range("A1:B95").CopyFromRecordset rst rst.Close
```

Comment: this is a followup to the old post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965337/update-existing-embedded-chart-in-powerpoint-using-excel-vba?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: What's powerpoint got to do with this??  is `chtData` an excel object?

Comment: sorry most of my message wasnt clear as i was following up. So i have a chart in powerpoint which i am trying to update using data from sql server. The chart has an embedded workbook within powerpoint. I am activating the workbook behind the chart and refreshing the data using data from a recordset. does this make sense?

Comment: Does `chtData` contain anything, in the original post you have a lot of assumptions, check each object to see if it's created/referenced properly.

Comment: it opens the workbook behind the chart. so the reference is working. I am copying the data from sqlserver into recordset. that piece is working too. But when i try to paste the data from record set into the chartdata workbook, its not working. Any help on your end will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post a complete question, with the code, whether it used to work/not now, what's changed etc.

Comment: Hi Nathan, sorry for the loss of clarity: my question is below. i have a powerpoint slide with 1 chart. This chart has data in a workbook behind the chart (chart in powerpoint). I want to update the data in this chart using output from a sql server. i wrote the VBA in powerpoint, i activate the chartdata (which opens the workbook in the chart). i get the data from SQL server into a record set. its the copy from record set into the chart data piece of code that i am not being able to work with. Can you please help me?>

Comment: Please show your code, the question in the link, is poorly done, so unsure of what answer you have used.

Comment: Sub ShowChartData()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim cht As Chart
Dim chtData As ChartData
Dim cTable As ObjectSet sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
'Assume the Chart is the second shape, modify if needed
Set shp = sld.Shapes("New")
'Handle the chart
Set cht = shp.Chart
'Handle the CharttData
Set chtData = cht.ChartData
chtData.ActivateWith chtData
    Set cTable = chtData.Workbook,   'sql connection and data:Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection  rst.Open StrQuery, Cn
  '  Dim wbs As Object
   cTable.Range("A1:B95").CopyFromRecordset rst
     rst.Close

Comment: Can you add it to your post, that's unreadable really.

Comment: i added it. Can you please advise? I have a deliverable due today and really appreciate your help

Comment: What is the error?  Have you populated StrQuery?